# build jdk(openjdk-7) from source

Tags: makefile, jvm-hotspot, java

After downloading `openjdk-7-fcs-src-b147-27_jun_2011.zip` on my Ubuntu 11.10, i tried to build it from source.
There were some warning/errors in the beginning which I was able to correct except one.

It says

Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

what could be the value of JAVA_HOME i have no idea. I tried assigning 
JAVA_HOME="."  // the home directory of jdk, 
but then i get an error which is even more interesting ...
the error is :

ERROR: Your JAVA_HOME environment variable is set.  This will 
       most likely cause the build to fail.  Please unset it 
       and start your build again.

Now what could be the problem.
I have java on my machine but no javac as of now.

You'd ask why do i need to install jdk from the source in the first place.
The reason is I want to build hotspot, and make some changes to it and then rebuild it.
The problem is it ruined my whole day to figure out how to build hotspot standalone.
So I thought may be I can build jdk which has inbuilt hotspot.. and then i can rebuild it from there as and when required.

If there is some method to build hotspot(from source), that also would be very helpful.

Comment: [Here](http://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/java7-openjdk)'s the openjdk `PKGBUILD` from Arch Linux. If you aren't familiar, it's simply a bash script that has the building/packaging instructions in it. Are you doing anything different?

Comment: Try this. The above one suggested by Can Celasum also works though. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Comment: @Can Celasun actually I am on Ubuntu. so i'm not sure how to use PKGBUILD.

Comment: @AdityaKumar Basically, the `build()` function configures and builds the jdk source. Then, executing the code from `package_jdk7-openjdk()` should install it.

Comment: I had the same problem, solved it by unsetting JAVA_HOME and symlinking my existing /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun to /NO_BOOTDIR

Answer (score 1):

Dont set your java home, unset it, the openjdk build manipualtes this itself during the build.

If it is set somehow and the sanity was to ignore it you get a really odd JVM as a result

try `unset JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 1):

build hotspot only,you can: make hotspot-build

find more make target at Makefile and make/hotspot-rules.gmk